# How to display a custom post type's media library inline on meta box

Tags: metabox, media-library

I am trying to create a post type which only displays the Media Library Inline.

I have got the example from this : https://gist.github.com/897503

However, nothing happens when I click "Insert Gallery". The code is as below.

Thanks in advanced!

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_gallery' );
function create_post_type_gallery() {
 $args = array(
  'labels' => post_type_labels( 'Gallery', 'Galleries' ),
  'public' => true,
  'publicly_queryable' => true,
  'register_meta_box_cb' => 'my_gallery_meta_box',
  'show_ui' => true, 
  'show_in_menu' => true, 
  'query_var' => true,
  'rewrite' => true,
  'capability_type' => 'post',
  'has_archive' => false, 
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'menu_position' => null,
  'supports' => array('title','editor' )
); 

register_post_type( 'gallery', $args );
}

function my_gallery_meta_box () {
  add_meta_box('gallery_details' , 'Media Library',     'my_gallery_meta_box_details', 'gallery', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function my_gallery_meta_box_details () {
  global $post;
  $post_ID = $post->ID; // global used by get_upload_iframe_src
  printf( "<iframe frameborder='0' src=' %s ' style='width: 100%%; height: 500px;'>   </iframe>", get_upload_iframe_src('media') );
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely incomplete. Example: `width: 100%%` and the function `post_type_labels()` doesn't exist in core - you should get an error there.

Comment: post_type_labels function is created by me. No problem with that function.  I am guessing the width is just part of css styling, should not be an issue

Comment: Btw, the code above works! Just add 'editor' also in the supports.

Comment: Yes. I was talking about the double `%`-character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at my [Gallery Metabox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gallery-metabox/) plugin to see how to build one, or you could just use the plugin itself. There's [a filter](http://www.billerickson.net/code/gallery-metabox-custom-post-types/) for specifying the post types it applies to.

Comment: Thanks. Plugin is cool. Anyway, the code above I pasted also does work :) My mistake on not allowing the editor.